# How to parse string to groups?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following `string`:

```
0 0.123 1.43 4 hello
```

and I need to parse it using regexp and extract all numbers float and integer.
I need something like this:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\d+([\.\,]\d+)?)+").matcher("0 0.123 1.43 4 hello");
int d = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0));
int d1 = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
int d2 = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
```

How can I do it?

Comment: @GlennvanAcker this code not working.

Comment: I deleted my comments, no point in trying. i didn't see it's java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex

```
String regex = "\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("0 0.123 1.43 4 hello");

while (matcher.find()) {
    String number = matcher.group();
    // number can be integer or float
}
```